# Retrieve children tree of user groups

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I need a help. I'm really stuck on this. I want to retrieve user group by name and all of sub-groups of that group.

For example if we have a tree like this one:

```
- Group 1 
-- Sub-Group 1
-- Sub-Group 2
--- Sub-Group 2.1
-- Sub-Group 3
```

What I want to score? I want to get Group 1 by its name and automatically retrieve all children of that group and save it in an array.

Every kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own so far? Any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a usergroups table, which contains all info you need: id, parent_id and title. Using these fields you may retrieve the whole tree. Group with parend ID 0 is a general Public group. The rest of the groups have parent IDs. So if you know PHP and basic SQL, you'll easily get groups tree.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it on the way that you have suggest.

Comment: Is there really no build-in API call for this in Joomla?? It seems like the sort of thing that should exist.